# WooCommerce: Adding custom items to a manual order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I run a reselling store. and I take requests from people for products that are not in my store. I search in the market and send it to the customer.

some of there products I add to my store. this is how my store collection expands day to day. but some times i dont want to add a product to my store because it is not related to the taste of my website.

There is a plugin called "Phone Orders for woocommerce". this plugin allows added of a custom item in manual order but it also creates that item in the store, which I want avoid.

Please help me finding the solution, maybe some plugin or some code that will help me solve the problem.

thanks.

Comment: I am just curious to see your store to see how you take requests. Can you share the link? It may give me a better idea to offer a solution. Thanks

Comment: @KoolPal 
thanks for your interest. My store is about books. there is nothing special about how I take requests. It is a simple CF7 form with some fields, like, Books Name. Author name, and Publisher. Name of book and Author is Required because this is how I search for the book in market. if user provides publisher that is really helpful.
there are more required fields like Your name, number and email. 
that is how if inform user about price and process.

Comment: @KoolPal 
I get the email and I start working on the requests. Most of the time I get requests through social media. because I have made it clear that I can find you books from the market. After finding the book there are two options. I can simply add the book to the store and send user a link to place order. Or I just simply send book to the user. My business mostly work on Cash on delivery. so no payment gateway involved. some time bank transfers but no big problem because that process already involves manual verification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Zahid, thanks for the detailed explanation.

I can think of one solution which you can test without the need for any plugins.

Create a blank product - call it Requested Book. Keep price empty. Save this product.

Whenever you get a request, select this product (Requested Book) during your manual order creation.

Once added, click on edit and change price.

Click on Add Meta button below this Requested Book name. Add Name = Book Name and Value = 1 Book or 1 Dozen Books (as the case may be)

Save.

Does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. this is really great tip, and it solves the problem. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Glad I could help. All the best!